# Interface Builder: Instantiate and Populate Arrays/Collections?

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

I'd just like to make sure that this is impossible. I'm coding around it, but I thought that IB would allow me to instantiate an `NSArray` and point it to objects in the NIB. This is impossible, right?

[I'm looking for a tiny bit more than "yep, it's impossible" so I can evaluate the answers. Obviously if someone knows how to do this, that would be much better.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No , not impossible just not particularly useful. But I dont know what you are up to :-)

Drag a generic NSObject from the toolbox to the .xib window and recast (Class Identity) it in the inspector (last tab with info icon)

Probably you want a NSMutableArray and then you can attach an outlet from the Files Owner to  the NSArray object and manipulate it from your code.

However I think you might find an NSArrayController to be a better use of your time.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to supply its contents in IB via connections. I'll check out `NSArrayController` though, that sounds interesting.